# How to limit number of job instance of particular class concurrent execution in quartz scheduler?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have a class "Applier" which implement Job .
Means class "Applier" is one of instance of Quartz Job.

My requirement is to control number of instance of "Applier" execute at a time.
Means i want to make limit like at a time maximum 5 instance of "Applier" execute.
If 6th instance of  "Applier" come and 5 instance already executing than it must have to wait until one of the instance of "Applier" completed.

Is there any  wait/notify type mechanism in Quartz Scheduler. Means if 6th instance of Job try to run and 5 instance of already executing than 6th instance must have to wait and notify after any of the 5 instance execution completed.

Means i want to achive some ThreadPool type mechanism  for particular instance of Job .
I do not want ThreadPool Like mechanisum at Quartz Scheduler level b'coz it is already provided by the Quartz Scheduler.

Comment: My case is  many quartz job JOB to single job(Quartz class) senario. 
JOB(Quartz Job) -> Job(Quartz class) 
Many to One
I have put all my "Applier" class in same group.
I have also put Trigger in same group also.
I try to get control using  JobListner but Quartz's "scheduler" class's "pauseJob" not work for JOB which is schedule for only 1 time execution.
I am not able to find any mechanism which can "pause" execution of particular group.
I have also check "JobFactory" but it is also not useful in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can either limit the number of jobs that run concurrently (threadpool) or you can limit a given instance of job to only one concurrent instance. You can't limit a given job to only a given number of instances (other than 1). The only way to do what you want to do is to only run one kind of job for a given scheduler and then limit the threadpool to the number of jobs you want running at the same tieme

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you are aware of this but, all jobs are unique to jobkey.

> Lets start with a convention for this answer
>
> JOB -- This means a quartz job
>
> Job -- Quartz job class

As I was mentioning earlier there can be only one instance of a JOB. How this happens is, each JOB is defined by a jobkey, now jobkey is always unique

This means generally you have one to one mapping between JOB and Job, i.e. a scheduled job (QuartZ job and class implementing the interface Job

which is JOB -> Job

> CASE 1

multiple instances of Jobs and not multiple instance of JOBs

which will look like

> JOB A -> Job |
>
> JOB B -> Job |...........Multiple JOB running same class
>
> JOB C -> Job |

Simply keeping a different jobkey in same jobgroup allows you to load multiple instances of Job to your scheduler

Have a look at [JobFactory](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/spi/JobFactory.html) because

> A JobFactory is responsible for producing instances of Job classes.

..

> CASE 2

Now coming to instances of JOB. based on your schedule and the execution time of the JOB, there can be multiple instances running parallelly (it is improper to call it as multiple instance better term would be concurrent execution). TO avoid that you will have to write some custom logic.
Or use annotation [DisallowConcurrentExecution](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html).

Load 5 instance of the Job as shown in CASE 1 which have DisallowConcurrentExecution. But this will mean 5 unnecessary instances, even though at a time the job may not be needed.

> CASE 3

Now lets consider setting a flag initialized to 1. A custom logic which may help handling this

Before you start you Job. you can check if the flag is less than 5. If less than 5 enter to the main business logic and increment the value of flag. After end of execution before coming out of the block decrement it. This way the business logic will not be executed even if you have multiple instances of JOB running.

```
    private static int jobRunningFlag = 0;

    @Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    if(JobName.jobRunningFlag <= 5)
        {
            JobName.jobRunningFlag++
    .....execute this piece of code....
            JobName.jobRunningFlag--
    }
}
```

Obviously jobRunningFlag will be a static variable stored in same Job class

> PS:
>   More answer to this would be based on your comments. Have you looked over JobFactory and related classes/interfaces. What have you tried. My idea is this will come down totally onto your implementation logic. I am not very good with quartz do not have much idea about them.

Comment: My case is  many quartz job JOB to single job(Quartz class) senario. 
JOB(Quartz Job) -> Job(Quartz class) 
Many to One
I have put all my "Applier" class in same group.
I have also put Trigger in same group also.
I try to get control using  JobListner but Quartz's "scheduler" class's "pauseJob" not work for JOB which is schedule for only 1 time execution.
I am not able to find any mechanism which can "pause" execution of particular group.
I have also check "JobFactory" but it is also not useful in my case. JobFactory implementing class does not provide any special mechanism to "pause" method.

Comment: i also tried to figure out a way for this. you can maybe look into EJB scheduler. or it comes down to trick plays like CASE 3, which would mean custom logic. I will update few things to my answer try to look over them

Comment: On entering the execute method call first check Job does is against a flag variable and value stored in it. And actual execution of the job be moved inside the conditional logic

Comment: I have try to solve problem using "wait" and "notify" mechanism of thread and problem solve at some level. But drawback of this mechanism is that if there are 100 "Object" waiting for lock than JVM heap memory increase. Means JVM heap memory will increase as number of waiting object increase.

Comment: interesting. I do not think you are creating scheduled job, you are simply trying to spawn threads. please mention at what schedule your job is running. With what heap size are you working. In what scenario you get 100 objects. You have a lot of constraints which it seems you have not mentioned.

Comment: you can get the number of instances of current running jobs via Quartz Api and don't schedule it....you can also restrict or find the occurances inside the jobexecution method and don't proceed if the number is greater than your expectation