# Quartz Recommendations for Multiple User Initiated Tasks

Tags: grails, parallel-processing, quartz-scheduler

Although I have some experience with Quartz previously, I am setting it up from scratch for the first time on an existing project.  We have decided to use Quartz (in part) to prepare for future requirements.

I am looking for suggestions / recommendations on the following:

**Requirements**

- There will be several different kinds of user-initiated tasks, each one taking anywhere from several seconds to several minutes.  These need to be executed asynchronously from the user requesting them, and be initiated even if the user logs out in the interim.
- These tasks will be grouped into categories.
- Within each category, only n (configurable) tasks should execute at a time
- Each user must be able to retrieve a list of tasks they he/she initiated
- Administrators must be able to retrieve a list of tasks for all users
- Tasks must be cancellable in the middle of executing
- Tasks must be cancellable while queued
- If there is a failure, any tasks that were being executed need to recover and restart
- Clustering must be supprorted

**Options**

I see the following options for implementation, and would really appreciate some feedback.

1. **Mostly Self Managed**

   - Maintain my own separate tasks table, with columns for scheduled time, user, status, etc.
   - Have a Quartz job per group that runs every x seconds, checks for the next task in the table, and executes it in parallel.
   - I am not sure how to achieve n parallel executions in this case besides n Quartz jobs per group.
   - I would expect in this case that Quartz would not need anything persisted over a restart, although it means that my code has to handle that case.
   - If no tasks are scheduled, the Quartz job would still fire
2. **Quartz Managed**

   - Each task becomes a separate Quartz Job.
   - I am not sure in this case how to allow n parallel Jobs per group.  It seems that the Quartz annotations can be used to prevent more than one parallel Job at a time.
   - Quartz tables would need to be persisted in the database.
   - Quartz itself would be responsible for recovery after a restart.
   - If no tasks are scheduled, then no Quartz jobs would fire.
3. **Something else?**

I am not sure (ahead of time) how easily each of the above corresponds to the requirements.

I would appreciate any feedback based on what I have written above.  I cannot find a lot of guidelines about this as most seem limited to Quartz jobs running at specific intervals or times and executing specific tasks independent of user-scheduling or user-request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure what are you talking about

**Mostly Self Managed** -- this sounds more like you are going to write up your own scheduler

**Quartz Managed** -- once added to scheduler all the jobs are quartz managed only

> > To do any change you simply need to write up something which you can call Manager class, which can stop a specific job and etc etc.
> >
> > Any job runs parallel only if the time interval for execution is very more that the scheduled interval.
> >
> > Running only one job at a time simply means you are using @DisallowConcurrentExecution, to disable any concurrent execution of the specific job. To have specifically a count of job instances to run per group you will need to write some custom logic.
> >
> > Hint: All Quartz job are passed JobExecutionContext, find out which jobgroup it is. Add then .......... think for yourself.
> >
> > you can check how to have Quartz job persistence. Again do it yourself. I am sure Quartz have enough information around this and how to achieve it.

Please remember all APIs not just QuartZ provide a set of actions. But the implementation and how to use them comes onto the developer. There is always fixed outline provided and how to guide available. Java is one language having huge documentation available.

---

You may get helped by this discussion
[Controlling instances of Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978738/how-to-limit-number-of-job-instance-of-particular-class-concurrent-execution-in/19988371#19988371)

---

BTW it is going to be your own custom implementation. I have not tried checking any of the quartz plugins available right now.

---

Just thought another solution. In case you have any UI interface or something adding the tasks. and any intervals (again ..........)

What you may do is, write your jobs into a stack
The QuartZ job may simply read the stack and load it as a separate thread.

Create a thread pool with fixed number of threads. IN this thread pool we can spawn the thread.

This way you can control number of threads

I think this is coming more as a implementation plan

Comment: Hi Acewin.  Thank you for your response.  I have thought about your questions, and have been doing more reading.  I can now better (hopefully) rephrase my question this way:  Users kick off tasks.  I want to use Quartz to schedule and limit the number of simultaneous tasks being run.  Am I better off to (a) have one Quartz job instance per task, and use a dedicated special Quartz job to trigger them as needed, or (b) to have a single Quartz job and create n triggers at a time based on the number of jobs outstanding.  Does that clarify my question?

Comment: yeah, now being clear on how to proceed you should be able to come up with a solution plan as well. When there is overhead in the usage of API only way to counter that is the implementation solution